# Partial match between two columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two columns that I want to partial match to each other.

For example:

```
A, B
Birmingham Hoover, Hoover Birmingham Area
```

These two columns should mean one area but when using contains functions, it didn't catch it. Do you know if there is function I can partially match these two columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **`.rlike`** function.

- **split** `column B` value by `" "` concatinating with `|` then matching with rlike, So any **word matches** with A column will be filtered out

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('Birmingham Hoover','Hoover Birmingham Area'),('ABCD',"Z Y Z U")],['A','B'])

df.show()
#+-----------------+----------------------+
#|A                |B                     |
#+-----------------+----------------------+
#|Birmingham Hoover|Hoover Birmingham Area|
#|ABCD             |Z Y Z U               |
#+-----------------+----------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#splitting B col value by " " concatinating with | then matching with rlike
df.withColumn("B",concat_ws("|",split(col("B")," "))).\
filter(expr('A rlike B')).\
show(10,False)
#+-----------------+----------------------+
#|A                |B                     |
#+-----------------+----------------------+
#|Birmingham Hoover|Hoover|Birmingham|Area|
#+-----------------+----------------------+
```